Put information in the statusbar of apple watch
I am trying to make use of the statusbar of the Apple Watch. Right now, it shows a semi-transparent bar with only the time on the right side. The rest of the bar is just wasted empty space. And because the Apple Watch screen is tiny, this matters.
Ideally, I would like to have no statusbar at all (the users of my app are not interested in the time while using the app), but I understand that is not possible.
I would settle for putting some useful information next to the time in the statusbar, any icons or text. I have tried several ways (such as using the navigationTitle of the top level view), but they all place the info under the statusbar.
The only way I have found, is to make sure the top view covers the whole screen, with a subview the same size as the statusbar at the top. But that is shown behind the semi-transparent bar, and looks just... weird.
Any hints for how to make this happen are appreciated. Surely, Apple must have recognised that using all available space is important on a tiny screen, right?
I am experienced in iOS programming, but are new to SwiftUI and Apple Watch.

The status bar can be hidden using the ._statusBarHidden() modifier.
Example:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            Text("Watch View")
                .padding()
            /* The following line hides the status bar */
                ._statusBarHidden()
        }
    }
}


Is that an undocumented feature on Apple Watch?
